# How to include a module inside another module while preserving their signatures?

Tags: types, module, ocaml

I'm trying to implement a small example of reusing modules inside other modules but so far I haven't succeeded fully.

What I'd like to achieve is to create 2 signatures - S and SE (with SE including S), and 2 modules - M (implementing S) and ME (implementing SE) with the purpose of not repeating previous code.

The bit I'm missing is including the contents of M inside ME:

```
module type S = sig
  type t
  val of_int : int -> t
end

module type SE = sig
  include S
  val to_string : t -> string
end

module M : S = struct
  type t = int
  let of_int x = x
end

module ME : SE = struct
  (* include M *)
  let to_string = string_of_int
end
```

Found a workaround so far by uncommenting `(* include M *)` in ME and changing the definition of M to be `module M : S with type t = int = struct` but that kind of defeats the purpose of this exercise as it changes the definition of M from implementing S to implementing something that looks like S.

Surely there must be a proper solution to this exercise. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that once you have restricted the signature of `M` to `S`, there is not enough information left about `M.t` to implement a meaningful `to_string` function.

Indeed, a module of type `S` defines a black-box (abstract type) `t` that can be produced from an integer ... and that's all. In other words, you can only produce values of type `M.t` but never have any clue on the content of thoses values. Thus, the only option left for `to_string` is to ignore its argument, and return an unrelated string. For instance,

```
 module ME: SE = struct
   include M
   let to_string _ = "?"
 end
```

Defining `M` and `ME` in reverse order works better. First, we define the module with the more exhaustive API:

```
module ME : SE = struct
  type t = unit
  let of_int _ = ()
  let to_string () = "()"
end
```

then we can erase the `to_string` function with a signature constraint

```
module M: S = ME
```

The other option is to avoid making the type `t` abstract, as you discovered, by using either the exact module type `S with type t = int` or letting the compiler infers it.

In short, signature constraints are about information erasure: they allow to hide some information about an implementation. And hiding too much information can lead to useless modules.

Comment: Thanks @octachron for your valuable advice! Defining the more general module first and then erasing the functions through a signature constraint does indeed work in this example (although I reckon that it is not often used when dealing with code reuse in OCaml - maybe moving the common functionality in a functor instead would be a better fit). Lots of learning ahead I guess!