# Structures and Pattern Matching

Tags: struct, ocaml

I have a struct `Context` that as a type takes an association list from string to a custom type `process`.
I'm trying to pattern match to see if my struct is empty (this seems to work fine) however checking whether my struct contains elements is giving me the following error.

```
File "src/main.ml", line 131, characters 13-30:
131 |   | Context.((ext_ref,prc)::tl) ->
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a list
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type t
```

Here is the code that won't compile:

```
(* Finds a recv corresponding to a send stmt *)
let rec find_recv (ctx: Context.t) (external_ref:variable) =
  match ctx with 
  | Context.(empty) -> None 
  | Context.((ext_ref,prc)::tl) ->
    begin
       match prc with
       | Prc(_, _,Recv(_,_,chn,_)) -> if chn = external_ref then  Some prc else find_recv tl external_ref
       |_ -> find_recv tl external_ref
    end
```

Here is the signature for the 'Context' struct.

```
module type Context = sig
  type t 
  val empty : t
  val lookup : t -> string -> process
  val extend : t->string ->process -> t
  val filter : t->string ->t
end
```

Here is the instantiation of my `Context` module:

```
(** Instantiating a Process Table *)
module Context : Context = struct
  type t = (string * process) list

  let empty = []

  let lookup (ctx:t) (x:string): process=
    let chck = List.assoc_opt x ctx in match chck with 
    |Some i -> i
    |None -> Null("")

  let extend (ctx:t) (x:string) (ty:process) =
    (x, ty) :: ctx

  let filter ctx x =
    List.remove_assoc x ctx
end
```

I got this code from the Real World Ocaml book.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Most importantly the definition of the `Context` module type. My hunch is that it makes `t` abstract, hiding its definition form the outside.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74031060

Comment: Also the pattern `Context.(empty)` will bind the value you match on to the name `empty` in the scope of that branch. It won't do a comparison against the value of `Context.empty`.

Comment: @glennsl I edited the question to include the Context modules definition.

Comment: Yes, so the problem is as I pointed out, and as the linked question explains. You're hiding the definition, therefore you can't use it outside the module. A possible solution is to create a generic `Context.find` function and use that instead, or even just move `find_recv` inside `Context`.

Comment: Yes you're right find_recv should go inside of the Context module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the constraints of your `Context` signature, type `t` within the `Context` module is abstract.

Within the module, your functions know that `empty` is a list. However, outside of it, `empty` is merely of abstract type `Context.t`.

Let's look at a simpler example:

```
utop # module type S =
sig
  type t
  val empty : t
end

module M : S =
struct
  type t = int list
  let empty = []
end;;
module type S = sig type t val empty : t end
module M : S

utop # M.empty;;
- : M.t = <abstr>

utop # match M.empty with [] -> "hello" | _ -> "world";;
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a list
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type M.t
```

`M.t` is abstract. We know it exists, but not *how* it is implemented. This abstraction is frequently useful in designing applications.

It is possible to break this abstraction. Whether it's a good idea is a matter of opinion and outside of Stack Overflow's scope.

```
utop # module M2 : S with type t = int list =
struct
  type t = int list
  let empty = []
end;;
module M2 : sig type t = int list val empty : t end

utop # match M2.empty with [] -> "hello" | _ -> "world";;
- : string = "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

As kindly pointed out by @glennsl and as is explained better than I can in this thread [Unbound constructor error when using module signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74031060/unbound-constructor-error-when-using-module-signature)

My problem can be solved by including the `find_recv` function within the Modules signature as below.

```
module type Context = sig
  type t 
  val empty : t
  val lookup : t -> string -> process
  val extend : t->string ->process -> t
  val filter : t->string ->t
  val find_recv: t -> variable -> process option 
end
```

Obviously this must then be instantiated before use.