# How to call the constructor of a module

Tags: ocaml, opam

Assuming I have the following module **signature** and **implementation** in the same file named `monoids.ml`:

```ml
module type MonoidADT = sig
  type 'a monoid
  (* . . . *)
end

module Monoid : MonoidADT = struct
  type 'a monoid = Monoid of ('a list) * ('a -> 'a -> 'a) * ('a)
  (* . . . *)
end
```

How am I supposed to use a constructor, of the type defined in the implementation, in an other file (module)? Is it directly accesible or should I create something like a factory function with `'a monoid` as return type?

What I tried to do is simply open the module and call its constructor as I would do inside the module, but of course it doesn't work and gives me `Unbound constructor Monoid` error:

```ml
open Monoids.Monoid;;

let boolean_monoid = Monoid ([true; false], ( || ), false);;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a module inside another module while preserving their signatures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543765/how-to-include-a-module-inside-another-module-while-preserving-their-signatures)

Comment: Or [Unbound constructor error when using module signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74031060)

Comment: @glennsl no neither of them answer my question correctly

Comment: Really? Your own answer is essentially a copy of the one in the second link, except it also suggests a way to keep the type in the signature abstract. Perhaps you should read it again.

Comment: @glennsl yes, I mean, the second one is similar (as you said), but it proposes the solution to use an additional function, which I also have already mentioned in the question. The main focus of my question is whether there is an alternative way to this.

Comment: And it does provide an alternative, as you also did in your own answer, to expose the type definition so that the constructor can be used directly. It`s not clear to me why these solutions aren't good enough. It's hard to give an acceptable answer if you don't give an accurate description of the problem.

Comment: You should also describe the module type that you are defining. Otherwise it is unclear if the signature constraint that you are applying can result in an useful module. In general, signature constraints should not be used to check if a module implements a signature.

Answer (score 1):

Signature constraints remove information. Moreover, if you remove too much information you can perfectly end up with unusable module.

Typically, when you write

```
module Monoid : MonoidADT = struct
  ...
end
```

you are asking the compiler to restrict your monoid to the signature shared by every monoids. And if your monoid module type was the standard one:

```ml
module type MonoidADT = sig
  type t
  val e: t
  val ( * ): t -> t -> t
end
```

this would mean that you are restricting yourself to writing code that is compatible with the one element monoid:

```
module One = struct
  type t = unit
  let e = ()
  let ( * ) () () = ()
end
```

This is unlikely to be what you want.

If you only wish to check that your module is a subtype of some module type you can write:

```ml
module _ : MonoidADT = Monoid
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently defining the type in both signature and implementation resolve the error:

```ml
module type MonoidADT = sig
  type 'a monoid = Monoid of ('a list) * ('a -> 'a -> 'a) * ('a)
(* . . . *)
end

module Monoid : MonoidADT = struct
  type 'a monoid = Monoid of ('a list) * ('a -> 'a -> 'a) * ('a)
(* . . . *)
end
```

But what if I'd like to give a different implementation? The non-abstract signature limits me in the definition of the concrete module.